# How to create objects from ArrayList and add them to a hashmap in Java?

Tags: arrays, object, collections, hashmap

So I have an ArrayList called Tokens that contains a series of strings. I am trying to create an object from each of the String in ArrayList and add it to the HashMap. How would I do that in a for-loop or whatever way?

The hashmap parameters would be (String, Object), where the string(key) is the string at the index of the ArrayList and Object is the one I'm creating from that index. I just need help the logic/outline to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

for (String s : tokens) {
    map.put(s, new Object());
}
```

Comment: Please use the `edit` link under your answer to add information rather than putting it in a comment where it might not be seen. Please also format your code as code.